# Get available days between two days in java

Tags: java, datediff

I am newly for java, and i want to build booking system and now i try to get available days between two days without booked days. but, however my code running bad.

this is my code

```
Connection connection = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from A");
        ResultSet executeQuery = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (executeQuery.next()) {
            String refid = executeQuery.getString("REFID");
            statDate = executeQuery.getDate("Start_date");

            endDate = executeQuery.getDate("End_date");
            System.out.println("ref no : " + refid + "   statDate :" + statDate + "     end date :" + endDate);
            System.out.println("\n");
            int month = statDate.getMonth();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            //
            for (int i = 1; i < maxDay; i++) {
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i + 1);

                String format = df.format(cal.getTime());
                dateOfMonth.add(format);

                addDays = addDays(statDate, 2);

                if (df.format(cal.getTime()).equals("" + statDate) || df.format(cal.getTime()).equals("" + endDate)) {

                    //System.out.println(statDate + " is not available !");
                    System.out.println("---");

                } else {

                    int bDays = endDate.getDate() - statDate.getDate();
                    //System.out.println(bDays);

                    //===========
                    List<DateTime> between = getDateRange(DateTime.parse(statDate.toString()), DateTime.parse(endDate.toString()));

                    for (DateTime dateTime : between) {
                        Date da = dateTime.toDate();

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");                          
                        dateOfBooked.add(sdf.format(da));
                    }

                    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
                }

            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
```

this is my db script

```
insert into  A  values('1','ref1','2018-02-18','2018-02-25');
insert into  A  values('2','ref1','2018-03-10','2018-03-17');
insert into  A  values('3','ref1','2018-03-20','2018-03-27');
```

i try to get available days from thees booked days. how can i print only available days ?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j93h7.png)

Comment: *however my code running bad* - what does that mean? Is it not working?

Comment: that work, it s shows all of days. only i want display available days without booked days

Comment: @achAmháin plz see **output**

that's shows all of days, i want remove dates since 2018-06-21 to 2018-06-28 from my output

Comment: It’s pretty much code, and your requirements aren’t perfectly clear. It would be better if you could [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then quote your desired output precisely/verbatim and also be precise about how observed output differs, possibly also quoting that. Then I’m sure we can spot your issue pretty quickly.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` classes. They are not only long outdated, they also have design problems, the former in particular is notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). With JDBC 4.2 or higher you can get `LocalDate` values from `executeQuery.getObject("Start_date", LocalDate.class)`, etc.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for ur advice soo. i will do